# Arabic Character Support - Html (ASCII) - XNA

Tags: html, fonts, xna, ascii, xna-4.0

What is the extent of Arabic letters in HTML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<XnaContent xmlns:Graphics="ReLogic.Content.Pipeline">
    <Asset Type="Graphics:DynamicFontDescription">
        <FontName>aboodedcF1</FontName>
        <Size>14</Size>
        <Spacing>0</Spacing>
        <UseKerning>true</UseKerning>
        <Style>Bold</Style>
        <DefaultCharacter>*</DefaultCharacter>
        <VerticalOffset>DefaultFontAscent</VerticalOffset>
        <CharacterRegions>

            <CharacterRegion>
                <Start>&#x20;</Start>
                <End>&#xA9;</End>
            </CharacterRegion>

        </CharacterRegions>
    </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

between

```
<CharacterRegion>
                <Start>&#x20;</Start>
                <End>&#xA9;</End>
            </CharacterRegion>
```

I searched a lot on the internet and didn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- arabic Characters -->
        <CharacterRegion>
            <FontName>Anaqa</FontName> <!-- font name -->
            <Size>30</Size>
            <Style>Regular</Style>
            <Start>&#1536;</Start>
            <End>&#1791;</End>
        </CharacterRegion>
        
        <CharacterRegion>
            <FontName>Anaqa</FontName> <!-- font name -->
            <Size>30</Size>
            <Style>Regular</Style>
            <Start>&#65136;</Start>
            <End>&#65279;</End>
        </CharacterRegion>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).